# Intrusive defines in windows headers

Tags: c++, winapi

What is the best way to deal with intrusive `#define` statements in Windows headers?

They tend to emit errors when I really need to define a symbol with the same name, no matter if it is in a namespace or not.

I know some defines can be avoided with `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN`, but not all.

In this particular case, I'm hitting a `DELETE` define in `WinNT.h#6478` - and there are tons of pretty generic keywords like this.

My immediate thought is to do an `#undef` before declaring my constant, but that is a very unelegant solution. I can't easily rename my constants because they are directly translated to text strings and I need those to be exactly what they are now.

Other defines that come to mind are `GetFirstChild`/`GetNextSibling` in `windowsx.h` ... really?

Comment: Perhaps you could isolate the use of your own #defines to a source file that does not need to `#include <windows.h>`?

Comment: I'm not using defines, I'm declaring constants inside a namespace, but that doesn't prevent them from conflicting with microsoft defines. And obviously I need the constants to be accessible from different parts of the project, thus they are in a header file and, unavoidably, some source files that need windows.h will also include it.

Comment: This is why you shouldn't name things that aren't preprocessor macros in all-uppercase.  All-uppercase names should be reserved for preprocessor macros; that the practice got perverted into naming *all* constants in all uppercase is unfortunate.

Comment: No, the person who has written this #define should live in pain... Why the hell add a preprocessor macro with a common name like DELETE in a system header and f*ck up the entire include chain. Now I get this include through curl.h and cannot avoid it.

The same story with defines in X11 header with common names like 'Window', 'Time' 'Font'.

At least, they could have used some prefix, like WIN_DELETE or XWindow

Comment: Give example for symbol which is "really" necessary and cannot be changed to something with your prefix, underline, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Realistically, I think the cleanest solution would be to provide a wrapper header that would `#include <windows.h>` and `#undef` all the macros that are getting in your way. You would then include this wrapper header instead of `windows.h`.

Comment: I like this idea, though I guess I'll have to see how big this problem gets and will probably keep the undef in the one file that causes the conflicts for now.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution is not to include `<windows.h>`.  There
should be very, very few modules which need it, and in those,
you just have to avoid the symbols which `<windows.h>` defines.
Which shouldn't be too difficult, because those will be low
level wrappers which don't need to include anything of your
application.

Comment: But there's a significant potential problem if you do that. `<windows.h>` defines **hundreds** of names with macros, and many of them are reasonable function names (the typical problem is that `<windows.h>` appends an A or a W). If you use one of those names as the name of a member function in a header, you can end up with two different versions of that name in your source files, depending on whether you've `#include`d `<windows.h>`. Typically this shows up as a link error because the source file that defines the member function gives it a different name than what you declared it as.

Comment: @PeteBecker Yes.  You do have to avoid those names in the implementation files of your wrappers (which are the only files which should include `<windows.h>`).  That's one of the constraints of programming under Windows.  But if the wrappers are relatively thin enough, they won't define very many symbols.  And conflicts will normally prevent the code from compiling, so you'll notice them.  (I'm assuming here that you follow the generally recommended practice of including the header for what you are implementing _before_ anything else, including `<windows.h>`.)

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be "don't include `<windows.h>` unless it's absolutely necessary". In general, you want to isolate the system dependencies to a small set of code anyway, so including `<windows.h>` in files willy-nilly is a bad idea.

Comment: Problem is, if on one end of my program I have my constants, and on the other end I have the windows headers, there has to be a bridge somewhere in the middle that will have to use both.

Comment: There may be other problems to solve, yes. But the general principle is to keep the system dependencies to a small set of files.